# GitHub: Searching not only in the main repository, but in all the fork?

Tags: github

How to search not only in the main repository, but in all the fork?

Comment: I'm not sure they support that. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: There is a repository that is not active anymore, and in the original code I found one bug.
And there are plenty of active pre-forked repository, and I decided to look for, can someone corrected a similar error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested a query [like this one](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3a%2a/jquery%20jquery&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=):

```
repo:*/jquery jquery
```

In the hope of searching for any repo called jquery (which should include any fork of jquery/jquery), but:

```
 Invalid search query. Try quoting it.
```

So wildcards aren't supported for the `repo:` filter.

Comment: Still true with the new search https://github.com/blog/1381-a-whole-new-code-search